# The Grid Search (HackerRank) - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I'm a developer for a few years but I'm practicing my algorithm skills.

I'm faced with ["The Grid Search"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-grid-search) in HackerRank and even though I could solve it, I want to know if this is a decent method to do it.

PS: I'm trying to to do most of it with simple instructions, developing the whole logic instead of using pre-built functions. My objective is to improve my logical thought, not my knowledge of a language's magic methods.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys


t = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(t):
    R,C = input().strip().split(' ')
    R,C = [int(R),int(C)]
    G = []
    G_i = 0
    for G_i in range(R):
       G_t = list(input().strip())
       G.append(G_t)
    r,c = input().strip().split(' ')
    r,c = [int(r),int(c)]
    P = []
    P_i = 0
    for P_i in range(r):
       P_t = list(input().strip())
       P.append(P_t)

    mIsEqual = False

    #For each line of the matrix
    for a1 in range(0,len(G) - (len(P)-1)):
        #For each column of the given line
        for a2 in range(0,len(G[a1]) - (len(P[0])-1)):
            #If the top left value of the pattern matches the current value of the matrix, try to match it
            if(P[0][0] == G[a1][a2]):
                #If the pattern 'fits' horizontally in the matrix, try to match it
                if(len(P[0]) <= (len(G[a1]) - a2)):
                    #If the pattern 'fits' vertically in the matrix, try to match it
                    if(len(P) <= (len(G) - a1)):
                        #Match every single field of the pattern to the given area of the matrix.
                        for a3 in range(0,len(P)):
                            for a4 in range(0,len(P[0])):
                                #If the fields are equal mIsEqual is true
                                if(P[a3][a4] == G[a3+a1][a4+a2]):
                                    mIsEqual = True
                                else:
                                #If the fields are not equal stop matching this area of the matrix.
                                    mIsEqual = False
                                    break
                            #If one field in a line was not equal, stop matching this area of the matrix.
                            if(mIsEqual == False):
                                break
                    #If, after matching the whole area with the pattern mIsEqual is still true, the pattern is there.
                    if(mIsEqual):
                        break
        #If the pattern was found in the previous line, no need to keep this going.
        if(mIsEqual):
            break

    if(mIsEqual == True):
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

I'm looking for any suggestions to improve this script or, if you think it's completely wrong, the reason why this is not a good way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to post the question so others don't have to figure out what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Nice tip. To be fair, I swore I had pasted the link here.

Comment: Posting the link to explain what you are trying to do isn't really good enough, since I don't want to have to go to a different site and figure it out for myself. Please explain the point of the question, and any areas you think might need improvement.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the feedback. I'm not going to do this right now, since I'm not at home. But soon, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is better on a code review site.

Your algorithm as described looks roughly right.  However it would be easier to follow if you mentally chunked things into functions.  That would also  remove some duplicated code, and also reduces how much you need to write the same thing both in code and in commends.

Compare what you wrote with the following untested code.  Which is essentially what you wrote only with functions broken out and only one comment per function:

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys


# Read the dimensions then a matrix from stdin
def read_matrix():
    R,C = input().strip().split(' ')
    R,C = [int(R),int(C)]
    M = []
    M_i = 0
    for M_i in range(R):
       M_t = list(input().strip())
       M.append(M_t)
    return M


# See if P can be found anywhere in G.
def found_match_in(G, P):
    for a1 in range(0,len(G) - (len(P)-1)):
        for a2 in range(0,len(G[a1]) - (len(P[0])-1)):
            if found_match_at(G, P, a1, a2):
                return True
    return False


# See if P can be found in G at location (a1, a2).
def found_match_at(G, P, a1, a2):
    for a3 in range(0,len(P)):
        for a4 in range(0,len(P[0])):
            if G[a1+a3][a2+a4] != P[a3][a4]:
                return False
    return True


t = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(t):
    G = read_matrix()
    P = read_matrix()
    if found_match_in(G, P):
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```